# How to extract data of cell clicked grid.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gridjs

I am using Grid.js to render a table in react. I need to extract the data in one of the cells. When I map the args, I get two results back....a MouseEvent and 'n' which contains the data that I need. How do I extract the data out of the 'n' result? Below is an image of what I receive from my current code which is below the picture.

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API } from '../../config';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import { Grid, html, h } from 'gridjs';
import 'gridjs/dist/theme/mermaid.css';

const PendingUser = () => {
  const [pendingUser, setPendingUser] = useState({});

  const wrappedRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPendingUsers();
    setPendingUser(pendingUser);
    grid.render(wrappedRef.current);
  }, []);

  const getPendingUsers = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API}/admin/pendinguser`);
    await data.filter(user => {
      user.accountApproved ? setPendingUser(user) : setPendingUser();
    });
  };

  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const buttonValue = e.target.value;
    console.log(buttonValue);
    grid.on('rowClick', (...args) =>
      args.map(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
    );
  };

  const grid = new Grid({
    search: true,
    columns: [
      {
        name: 'ID',
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        name: 'First Name'
      },
      {
        name: 'Last Name'
      },
      {
        name: 'Email'
      },
      {
        name: 'Agency'
      },
      {
        name: 'Approve',
        formatter: (cell, row) => {
          return h(
            'button',
            {
              style: 'cursor: pointer',
              className: 'py-2 mb-2 px-2 border rounded text-white bg-success',
              value: 'approve',
              onClick: e => handleClick(e, 'value')
            },
            'Approve'
          );
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Deny',
        formatter: (cell, row) => {
          return h(
            'button',
            {
              styel: 'cursor: pointer',
              className: 'py-2 mb-2 px-2 border rounded text-white bg-danger',
              value: 'deny',
              onClick: e => handleClick(e, 'value')
            },
            'Deny'
          );
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Denied Reason',
        formatter: (_, row) =>
          html(
            '<select>' +
              '<center><option value="Non Law Enforcement">Non Law Enforcement</option><option value="Non Law Enforcement">Non US Law Enforcement</option></center>' +
              '</select>'
          )
      }
    ],
    server: {
      url: `${API}/admin/pendinguser`,
      method: 'GET',
      then: data =>
        data.map(user => [
          user._id,
          user.firstName,
          user.lastName,
          user.email,
          user.leAgency
        ])
    }
  });

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div ref={wrappedRef} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default PendingUser;
```

here is what the 'n' data looks like and I have circled what I want to extract. [image]

Comment: what your `n` data looks like and what exactly you want to extract from it?

Comment: @webcoder I have updated my question to reflect what the 'n' data looks like and what I want to extract from it.

Comment: don't know what is the value of `e.target.value`? if it is equal to `data` in one of the objects in `n` array then you can find it by using `find` method like: ` args.map(data => {
         const found = data.find(item => item.data === e.target.value)
         return found
      })`

Answer (score 0):

```
columns: [{ name: 'Name',
attributes: (cell) => {
// add these attributes to the td elements only
if (cell) {
return {
'data-cell-content':cell,
'onclick': () => alert(cell)
};
}
}},
```

This worked for me bro.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made